# Mathematical symbol for "solution set of"

Tags: notation

Is there a mathematical symbol for "solution set of"?

ex:
"$5 \in \text{[solution set of] } f$", or "$0 \notin \text{[solution set of] } g(x) =x^2+x-2$"

Comment: Also, while $x=5$ is true for the first example (assuming it's f(x) and not f(z) or something), it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: A useful shortcut for $$0\not\in\{x: g(x)=x^2+x-2=0\}$$ is simply $g(0)\neq 0$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Yes, but if I *wanted* to write it the long way, do I have to write it in set-builder?

Comment: You may use "for any $f(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, let $$ Z_f=\{x:f(x)=0\}$$" then simply use $Z_f$ to denote the zero set of $f$. I am not aware of any "standard notation".

Comment: It isn't uncommon to see $f^{-1}(0)$ or $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ used for this purpose.

Comment: Oh, sure, that is true.

Comment: I was trying to find an easier way to say "$\text{If } f(x)=x^2+1 \text{ then } 0 \notin \text{[solution set of] f}$. I guess $0 \notin \{x:f(x)=x^2+1\}$ works, but I was hoping for something that didn't use set builder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f:X\to Y$ is a function, the set of all points $x\in X$ so that $f(x)=y\in Y$ is commonly denoted $f^{-1}(\{y\})$. So if $5$ is a solution to $f(x)=0$, we could write $$5\in f^{-1}(\{0\}).$$ Some authors will write this as $f^{-1}(y)$, (without brackets), but I don't like this because it could be confused with a reference to the inverse of $f$, which may not even exist.

In fact, if $S\subset Y$, we can write the set of all $x\in X$ so that $f(x)\in S$ as $f^{-1}(S)$. Such a set is called the *preimage* of $S$.

Comment: Hmm.. So if 5 *wasn't* a solution, I'd use $5 \notin f^{-1}(\{0\})$?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Ah, nice and succinct! Thanks!